# Picking groups which have the same average from a sorted array

Tags: algorithm

I have a sorted int array and I want to get groups of N numbers and average of each group must be the same. Could anyone suggest an algorithm or give me any reference?

Comment: What have you already researched? Do you know how to get subsets of a given set?

Comment: @PM77-1 I know how to get a fixed number of subsets from a given set which their sum are equal. But in this case the number of subsets is not given, only number of elements in each subsets. The first idea of mine is to calculate the sum of each subsets and then insert the elements until it meets the sum. But I'm not sure if it's going to work or not

Comment: NP-hard.  Subset-sum problems can be reduced to the case where N is half the size of your array.  Which sorted int array do you have to do this to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing you are trying to do is popularly known as "partition problem". One of the naive approach is to use "Greedy algorithm". Other famous approaches for the problem are Differencing Algorithm and Anytime Algorithm. You can also solve the problem using either recursion or dynamic programming. This page provides you a detail to solve problem using recursion as well dynamic approach and also contains codes.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-partition-problem/

Comment: I decided to use Greedy algorithm for the case. Thank you!